# how to calculate asymptotic complexity of a for loop with a fixed number of iterations?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

def find1(L, ele):

"""L a list of ints, ele is an int"""

```
for i in range(100):
   for e1 in L:
     if e1 == ele:
       return True
return False
```

def find2(L, ele):
"""L a list of ints, ele is an int"""

```
for i in range(ele):
  for e1 in L:
   if e1 == ele:
     return True
return False
```

above are two functions,for find2 function i understand time complexity is O(len(e)*len(L))
for find1 the first for loop has fixed number 100 iterations,how  to calculate complexity for find1 function

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Why would you need two for loops? The inner loop does the exact same thing in each iteration in both methods.. Also your second method isn't `O(n^2)`, its `O(n*ele)`.

Comment: for loops are just to understand the concept of quadratic complexities. Both are different functions want to understand the asymptotic complexity for both functions